# Android Project ClassNotFoundException of Main Activity

Tags: android

I have trouble starting my app because my main activity can not be found:

```
12-28 21:47:22.271: E/AndroidRuntime(23923): 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
Didn't find class "de.myPath.activities.LoginActivity" on path: 
DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/de.myPath/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

I defined it properly in the Manifest.xml:

```
<activity
    android:name="de.myPath.activities.LoginActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
    android:launchMode="singleTask" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

I tried:

- cleaning
- rebuilding
- deleting / reimporting
- i checked my libraries

It happened after i added the google-play-services_lib to my project.

**Edit**

Actually no activity at all can be found anymore oO

Answer (score 0):

You defined it in your manifest.xml, but is there actually the file `de/myPath/activities/LoginActivity.java` and a class inside which is extending an android activity?

You will need this as well, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Ok What solved problem for me is to go to Properties of your project then go to Java Builth Path then to Order And Export after what you hit SELECT ALL and hit Ok.And you should be good to go.